# Laravel: Proper use of isset in If Statement

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement

I have a conditional: `if (isset($response['ad1'], $response['screen'])) { ... }`
Now I want to change the conditional to be if *either* `$response['ad1']` or `$response['ad2']` is set *and* `$response['screen']` is set.

Would that just be: `if (isset(($response['ad1'] || $response['ad2']), $response['screen'])) { ... }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ((isset($response['ad1']) || isset($response['ad2'])) && isset($response['screen']))
```

or

```
if (isset($response['screen']) && (isset($response['ad1']) || isset($response['ad2'])))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((isset($response['ad1']) || isset($response['ad2'])) && isset($response['screen']))
```

You can use this way

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if((isset($response['ad1']) || isset($response['ad2'])) && isset($response['screen']))
{
}
```